# Is there any way how to load environemnt variable from remote docker machine and not the local?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

We have docker machine created via:

`docker-machine create --driver generic --generic-ip-address=....`

when restarting containers from this machine, we're doing that from our local development machines via:

```
SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://....
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=...
SET DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=....
SET COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=true
```

now, we have environment variables configured in docker-compose

```
   environment:
      - SRV_VARIABLE=${SRV_VARIABLE}
```

but when we restart the server from our local system, docker-compose use `SRV_VARIABLE` located on our local computers and environment variable from the docker machine.

Is there any way, how to tell docker to use variable from the server and not from the local computer?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this without actually running `docker-compose` on the remote machine.  I think Compose fully processes the `docker-compose.yml` file including any environment variable expansions before it invokes the Docker API at all, and the Docker API doesn't include any way to read environment variables from any particular host process.

Comment: thanks for the reply. This is what I'm afraid of :(. So there is no way how to pass some server-side settings to docker machines at all. Maybe via mounting directory and storing these settings inside the shared folder.

Comment: If you have a `volumes:` bind mount, that will come from the host running the Docker daemon and not the host making the request, and that might make sense for you.